# How to set Startofweek in highcharts api

Tags: highcharts

Hi I am using Highcharts api for developing charts.

I want set the start of week value. I have tried in many ways but failed.

I saw that varible in the following json object.

```
var defaultXAxisOptions = {
    max: null,
    min: null,
    minPadding: 0.01,
    maxPadding: 0.01,
    //minRange: null,
    minorGridLineColor: '#E0E0E0',
    minorGridLineWidth: 1,
    minorTickColor: '#A0A0A0',
    minorTickLength: 2,
    minorTickPosition: 'outside', // inside or outside

    startOfWeek: 1,
    startOnTick: false,


    type: 'linear' // linear, logarithmic or datetime
},
```

The above object is taken from highstock.js

I want to override this in my js file.

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of your `defaultXAxisOptions`:

```
defaultXAxisOptions.startOfWeek=0;
```